# How to get any web site alert message UWP WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, webbrowser-control, invokescript

what am I doing wrong?

I used w3schools.com for testing.

```
webView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert"));
```

Package.appxmanifest file

[image]

NavigationCompleted

```
private async void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string result = await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "window.alert = function (AlertMessage) {window.external.notify(AlertMessage)}" });
}
```

ScriptNotify

```
private async void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
     MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(e.Value);
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: I want to get alert message [like this (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHbud.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is related to the web page
(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert) you are using to test.

If you inspect on this page, you will find the "Try it" button is actually in a `iframe` named "iframeResult".

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframeResult" name="iframeResult">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body contenteditable="false">
      <p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script>
          function myFunction() {
              alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
          }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

So your code won't work while clicking "Try it" as you are overriding **`window.alert`** which is the `alert` method in parent frame. And to make your code work, you can simply change it to **`iframeResult.window.alert`** like the following:

```
private async void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string result = await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "iframeResult.window.alert = function(AlertMessage) {window.external.notify(AlertMessage)}" });
}
```

Comment: This won't work on iframes from any other site, because the id `iframeResult` is specific to w3schools.